# NSPredicate with Core Data not returning data

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

When either of the following NSPredicates are used by themselves they return the data as expected.  However, when I do a compound search nothing is returned.  What is incorrect with my search?  I'm searching Core Data with an NSFetchRequest

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"File"];

NSPredicate *rootPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileWithContents.entityFolderRoot.object_id == %@", self.product.iqid];
NSPredicate *pathPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileWithContents.path == %@", self.currentFolder.path];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pathPredicate, rootPredicate, nil]];

request.predicate = rootPredicate;
[self performFetchWithRequest:request];
```

Comment: You did verify there are in fact objects that satisfy both conditions by looking at the persistent store?

Comment: Did you mean `request.predicate = predicate;`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the attribute names in your predicate it seems that your data structure is perhaps unnecessarily complex. Why would an entity representing a file (`File`) have a to-one relationship to another file (`fileWithContents`) which besides a `path` attribute would have another to-one relationship with another entity describing some kind of folder (`entityFolderRoot`) which as a unique ID.

Indeed, the path attribute and the folder root relationship seem to be describing a similar thing (some kind of container), maybe the same thing. This is bound to lead to unexpected results.

Consider redesigning your data model.